# typescript : generic interface with a collection of generic functions : Types of parameters XXX and 'args' are incompatible

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to create an interface that lists a bunch of functions that classes should implement.
However, I'm facing a weird typing issue `Types of parameters XXX  and 'args' are incompatible` when implementing the classes
Below is the code (running typescript 3.8.3) , [here is a link to typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=23&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGED2UIDECuICYwmIAzsgN4BQyyA5hGAIIA2bAPACoB8AFADphcKA3IAuZNwDaAXQCUUuCACeAbhoBfGjVCRYiFKlzAo5MJ1y9qdZADc4bfBAm5tu-dHhI0AZQgEMgATTj8bWnpguDA4CT8PGgQ2OHJKdDZybggLHmyLAEZkCAAPSBBgygsoUAYbYABbAAc2CAaIcEoMbDxCYlIKWzsm-AAjNmAERmZ2Nn5HNgAhTEw2CRMzXNGV1pVeABoHJz8wGpAGdYCgis5q2t4laXywArtI%20mRri2QwCW5nooAXmQACIQXZ6F9VhBBGxMAx5k5lqtDgsTmcGAoIcgcGB8FAQD87DpdFogA)

```
interface ICoreFunctions {
    getAll<T>(...args: T[]): any;
  }

  interface IFirst<F> {
    value:F
  }

  interface ISecond<S> {
    data:S
  }

  class ClsTest<TTest1 extends string> implements ICoreFunctions {

    public getAll(valBool:IFirst<boolean>, valString:ISecond<string>, num:number): TTest1   <-----Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'IFirst<boolean>'
    {
      const t:TTest1 = ""
      console.log(valBool, valString,num)
      return t
    }


  }

  class Cls2 implements ICoreFunctions {
      public getAll():void {    <--- no error here
          console.log("test2")
      }
  }
```

Comment: Using `...args: T[]` means thaty every argument should have the **same** signature, furthermore since you are implementing a generic method, it should be generic. if you want just the interface to be generic, lift up the generic as `ICoreFunction<T>`

Comment: The use case isn't clear to me here; what's the point of the generic exactly?  I mean, maybe `interface ICoreFunctions { getAll(...args: any): any; }` is good enough?   If I have a value `cf` of type `ICoreFunctions`, with what parameters should I be allowed to call `cf.getAll(...)`?  I think it would be useful to see some minimal test suite where you show code that you expect to be accepted and code where you expect to see errors.

Comment: The use case :  want to implement an interface that lists the CRUD methods (list, delete, ...). Why ? Because I want the same name for each CRUD methods whatever the framework that is applying them. For example, I need to create "crud actions" for redux, as well as crud method for typeorm repository and crud resolvers for graphql. E.g  the LIST crud method should be implemented as a reducer, but also as a redux action and a typeorm method. Of course, although they have the same name (LIST) the signature is different as they required different parameters and returns different types

Comment: the idea is that I could create classes for redux, typeorm and graphql, that all implements this interface. So that all classes should at list implement the bunch of CRUD actions of the interface. Again although the name of the methods are the same among the Classes, each method has a different signature. That is why I want them to be generic and be able to pass the args types when implementing them in the Classes